# Build fails with latest version of vite, vercel-adapter and sveltekit

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have updated my npm dependencies to their latest versions and now I am not able to create a build. The error I am getting is *Transform failed with 2 errors: Unterminated string token*. I checked my HTML files where mostly CSS classes are inlined because I use tailwind CSS but all the files had classes in one line. I am not able to find out where the issue is.

**My pacakage.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.19.1",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-vercel": "^1.0.0-next.47",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.3.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^3.2.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.5",
        "postcss-load-config": "^3.1.1",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.5.0",
        "svelte": "^3.44.0",
        "svelte-check": "^2.2.6",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.12",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1",
        "typescript": "~4.6.2"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@floating-ui/dom": "^0.4.4",
        "cookie": "^0.4.2",
        "notyf": "^3.10.0",
        "swiper": "^8.0.7",
        "ts-results": "^3.3.0"
    }
```

**Log**

```
rendering chunks (7)...[vite:css-post] Transform failed with 2 errors:
<stdin>:1:73: ERROR: Unterminated string token
<stdin>:2:55: ERROR: Unterminated string token
> Transform failed with 2 errors:
<stdin>:1:73: ERROR: Unterminated string token
<stdin>:2:55: ERROR: Unterminated string token
<stdin>:1:73: ERROR: Unterminated string token
<stdin>:2:55: ERROR: Unterminated string token
    at failureErrorWithLog (E:\StoreBud\storebud-storefront\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1603:15)
    at E:\StoreBud\storebud-storefront\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1392:29
    at E:\StoreBud\storebud-storefront\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:666:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (E:\StoreBud\storebud-storefront\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:763:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (E:\StoreBud\storebud-storefront\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:632:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this issue was caused because of the app.css file added by `npx svelte-add@latest tailwindcss` project used to add tailwind CSS to sveltekit. Specifically, issue was being caused by the comment added at the top of app.css. On removing the comment, I was able to build the project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When getting errors like this it also helps to bump `@sveltejs/kit` as well.

I found this searching the error message `TypeError: builder.getAppPath is not a function` with the accompanying solution on a GitHub issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/7284#issuecomment-1281026050